# AngularJS Filter Search terms from the front instead of the entire property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, search, controller

I am having trouble figuring out how exactly to go about filtering out results in my application.

I have an array `gameList` with a bunch of game objects in it. For our purposes, let's just say that I want to search by `game.name` only. If I have a game named `Apple`, a game named `Orange`, and one named `Oddball`. Right now typing an `a` into the search bar will still leave all 3 entries showing, because the letter `a` is contained in both `Orange` and `Oddball`. What I want to happen is for `Orange` and `Oddball` to be filtered out because it does not begin with `a`. However if I type an `O` I would want `Apple` to be filtered out, and then the next letter in the searchbox (`Or` or `Od`) would determine what gets filtered out.

I have had a hard time finding a method to do this. It's possible that I may just not be using the right search terms when I'm looking. How do I compare my variable `searchText` with `game.name` from the beginning as opposed to the entire string???

View/Page Code:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchController" class="content"> 
  <h2 id="pageTitle">{{pageTitle}}</h2>

  <label>Search: <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" ng-model="searchText"></label>
  <div ng-repeat="game in gameList | filter:searchText" class="gameDiv">
    <h3>{{game.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{game.numPlayers}}</p>
    <p>{{game.duration}}</p>
    <a ng-href="#!game-info/{{game.gameId}}">More Info</a>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
rwagApp.controller("SearchController",  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pageTitle = "Search";
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $http.get("http://localhost/list?table=games").then(function (data) {
        $scope.gameList = data.data.arr;                
    }); 
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you observed is the behavior of the filter - what you could do is to create a custom filter which would look at the start of the game's name when matching with the search input; Demo code below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("SearchController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pageTitle = "Search (by first word onwards)";
    $scope.searchText = '';
    /*    $http.get("http://localhost/list?table=games").then(function (data) {        $scope.gameList = data.data.arr;                    }); 
        /* mocking games list */
    $scope.gameList = [{
      name: 'apple',
      numPlayers: 10,
      duration: 60
    }, {
      name: 'orange',
      numPlayers: 25,
      duration: 60
    }, {
      name: 'mango',
      numPlayers: 100,
      duration: 60
    }, {
      name: 'banana',
      numPlayers: 50,
      duration: 60
    }, {
      name: 'watermelon',
      numPlayers: 30,
      duration: 60
    }];
  }])
  .filter('firstWordFilter', function() {
    return function(val, toSearch) {
      var filteredArray = [];
      if (toSearch != '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
          if (val[i].name.toLowerCase().search(toSearch.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
            filteredArray.push(val[i]);
          }
        }
        return filteredArray;
      }
      //Comment this else statement if you want nothing by-default
      else {
        return val;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchController" class="content">
  <h2 id="pageTitle">{{pageTitle}}</h2>

  <label>Search:
            <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" ng-model="searchText">
        </label>
  <div ng-repeat="game in gameList | firstWordFilter:searchText " class="gameDiv">
    <h3>{{game.name }}</h3>
    <p>{{game.numPlayers}} | {{game.duration}} |
      <a ng-href="#!game-info/{{game.gameId}}">More Info</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you put the custom filter inside the ng-repeat like this: `filter:myFilter` and replace the searchbox input, instead referencing `searchText` inside of the custom filter function, you can achieve this fairly easily using the str.substring function.

Page/View code:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchController" class="content"> 
  <h2 id="pageTitle">{{pageTitle}}</h2>

  <label>Search: <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" ng-model="searchText"></label>
  <div ng-repeat="game in gameList | filter:myFilter" class="gameDiv">
    <h3>{{game.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{game.numPlayers}}</p>
    <p>{{game.duration}}</p>
    <a ng-href="#!game-info/{{game.gameId}}">More Info</a>
  </div>    
</div>
```

My Controller code:

```
rwagApp.controller("SearchController",  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pageTitle = "Search";
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $http.get("http://localhost/list?table=games").then(function (data) {
        $scope.gameList = data.data.arr;                
    }); 

    // custom filter
    $scope.myFilter = function (game) {
        if ($scope.searchText === '') return true; //shows the entire list when the page boots up
        return game.name.substring(0, $scope.searchText.length) === $scope.searchText; //compares `game.name`'s first `searchText.length` number of characters with `$scope.searchText`
    };
}]);
```